# How to install the wireless LAN card driver on embedded Linux

Tags: wifi, embedded, yocto

I wanted to use AP mode with embedded Linux and wireless LAN card

I connected the wireless LAN card to the embedded board with USB, but the commands like ifconfig and iwconfig didn't recognize it

Looking at the response when I connected the USB, I think it was connected, but I thought it was not recognized because there was no Linux driver

By the way, I'm looking for related articles on the Internet and they say I have to use make oldconfig, but I can't make it or apt-get it, so how can I install the Linux driver? Please let me know the related sites

First of all, we tested the wireless LAN card to be in AP mode on normal Linux

[image]

development environment

Embedded board type : sama5d4

Wireless LAN card type : ipTIME A3000U

Compiling: yocto

access : putty -> minicom

Comment: "how to install things on my Linux environment" comes down to *what is your environment*? This might be trivial on say, a debian Linux, it might be very doable on your self-spun OpenEmbedded distro, or it might be a nightmare including building a compatible toolchain for your device to which you don't have SDK access, because the vendor violates the GPL or went bankrupt before you could ask them for such.

Comment: So you have a complete yocto repo to `bitbake` the image? And a driver for the WLAN chipset is part of the mainline kernel? Then what is the problem to change your `defconfig` to include the driver?